# How to read an Ical Feed using  java or javascript

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Im working on ene groupcalendar on Xpages and would import ICAL Files.

I would enter this this ULR: http://webtermine.de/?ec3_ical_nordrhein-westfalen

an use the responding ics file in my Calendar.

my Problem is how to get the file and read the content in java/javascript
I had no Idea how to do this and hoped that someone could help me

Comment: Java != JavaScript. Both are completely different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a java (not javascript) solution, you could use the [ical4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ical4j/) framework

Comment: my problem is not how to parse the ICAL file my problem is how to get the file that responses from the URL. or could ical4j recieve the response of the url?